# TesseractEngine does not release the traineddata file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, tesseract

After I run the following code I can not delete the `*.traineddata` file in `datapath` folder, until I completely closes the program.

```
Shared Function GetOcrText(ByVal imagePath As String,
                         ByVal datapath As String,
                         ByVal languages As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String

    Dim languagesStr = String.Join("+", languages)
    Dim resultText As String = ""

    Using engine = New TesseractEngine(datapath, languagesStr, EngineMode.Default)
        Using img = Pix.LoadFromFile(imagePath)
            Using page = engine.Process(img)
                resultText = page.GetText()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return resultText

End Function
```

Am I wrong about something?

What should I do to be able to delete the file?

Answer (score 0):

Use [3.2.0-alpha4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/3.2.0-alpha4) version of .Net wrapper for tesseract-ocr.

I tried your code with this version and everything works fine.